# Can we increase lambda /tmp folder size ?, i Is there any method to append a file to S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that does some functions and generates a file. I have some append operation in this file so I write the file **/tmp** folder . after the process I upload to s3 . some times file size will bigger than 512mb so function fails. So is there any method I can write the file directly to s3. S3 does not support appending .I used python language in lambda

## #

after so many searches, There is a python package smart_open that allow you to write directly to the s3

> [smart_open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be changed. Its a fixed limit. You may consider the possibility that lambda is simply not suited for your use-case.

Comment: @Marcin is there anyway we can append files to s3 without saving in lambda /tmp ?

Comment: A really clunky workaround might be to use a [Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) to read the existing file and write it back to S3, while adding one more part at the end, keeping only as much data in memory/tmp as necessary. But it really sounds like S3 + Lambda is really a bad fit for your use case.

Comment: @deceze is there is any streaming file service for this ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda now support ephemeral storage up to 10GB https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-ephemeralstorage

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), the storage of the **/tmp** folder cannot exceeds 512 MB. It will be better to remove your logic from  lambdas and at the end of your process, you just need to upload file to S3 by using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html).
But if you are using image file, you can use [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.2/) to reduce file size before.

Comment: is there is any way to add python package to lambda

Comment: To add python package to lambda, this link 
 https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/  could help you